# How to fetch the specific data from website using regular expression?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm new to python web **scraping**. i'm trying to build one script that fetches only the normal texts under the bold ones fromthe website - https://www.state.gov/cuba-restricted-list/list-of-restricted-entities-and-subentities-associated-with-cuba-effective-january-8-2021/

i.e like only the texts MINFAR — Ministerio de las Fuerzas Armadas Revolucionarias and
MININT — Ministerio del Interior under the **Ministries** similarly upto the end **Additional Subentities of Habaguanexand** and store them as a list. I tried to fetch those with the following code. but i'm unable to fetch those normal text values alone.

here is my code:

```
import requests

import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "https://www.state.gov/cuba-restricted-list/list-of-restricted-entities-and-subentities-associated-with-cuba-effective-january-8-2021/"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")

content = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'div' and tag.get('class') == ['entry-content'])

print(content)
```

Any ideas are heartly welcome friends. pls feel free to share your thoughts. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the HTML code of the site, to see what kind of format it had. It seems like all the items are wrapped in a div with a class of `entry-content` as you found yourself as well.
Then I also found that all the text is wrapped in `<p>` tags, but the headers we want to exclude are also wrapped in `<b>` tags within this p tag. This means we can filter out any tags that **start** with a `<b>` tag. It is important that we only filter out the tags that start with `<b>` because there are some valid entries like `<p>Gran Hotel Bristol Kempinski <b><i>Effective</i></b><b><i>November 15</i></b><b><i>, 2019</i></b></p>` that are entries in the list, but only have bold tags later in the wrapping `<p>` tag.

In the script I use `p.encode_contents()` to get the HTML as a string to see if it starts with a `<b>` tag. Note that this function returns a bytestring, so the comparison must be with another bytestring by using `b""`.
One more thing is that it skips the first two tags, because these belong to the description of the page.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.state.gov/cuba-restricted-list/list-of-restricted-entities-and-subentities-associated-with-cuba-effective-january-8-2021/"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")

content = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "entry-content"})[0]

results = []
for p in content.find_all('p')[2:]:
    if not p.encode_contents()[:3] == b"<b>" and p.text:
        results.append(p.text)

print(results)
```

This code goes over all `<p>` tags in the `.entry-content` tag, and checks to see if it starts with a `<b>` tag. Then only saves the text of the ones that don't. Finally it just prints the array with all the names.

Comment: Thank you soo much brother! for your valuable time in sharing this knowledge. Your explanation for every step was so good ad its really very much helped in learning a new ways for finding solutions. Thanks! again bro. Have a good day :)